# Open URL in other Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

This is my Android code:

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent();
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                    return true;
                }
```

I got this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent {  }

I want to set when people click on an url within a WebView, it will be opened in other fragment

How do I set it?

Comment: Is the above code in activity or fragment?

Comment: Im kind of new to programming, so ignore this if u get other answers, but you haven't provided any parameters to myIntent. I believe you need a FragmentActivity and pass the url to it and then startActivity should be called.

Comment: @AftabHussain right. an empty intent

Comment: @AbhishekShukla: it's in fragment :) 

@AftabHussain: I've tried using `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));` but it open on web browser. I want it to be opened in other fragment. Is that possible?

Comment: Seems like you are new to android..
You can use a webView for this purpose!!

Comment: Yeah, I'm newbie to Android :D

Comment: @AbhishekShukla: I'm already using WebView in a fragment (e.g: FragmentOne), the problem is to display the url content in another fragment (e.g: FragmentTwo). Thos two fragments are in the same Activity :)

Comment: Dude.. I guess you are confused.. does your problem revolve around Showing a web page in your app or it revolves around fragments? I guess both. :P

Comment: I have no problem to display a web page in my app. The problem is when I click the url within the page, it shows in the same page. What I want is to show it in other fragment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lack the class you want to start.
Assuming the activity you want to start is a navigator you should use:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(myIntent);
```

If, what you want to do is start an activity in your own app who takes the url as an extra:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("theUrl", url);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

If you want to display the info inside another fragment, (assuming you're already in a fragment) you can do something like:

```
try{
    MyWebviewFragment f = new MyWebViewFragment(url);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("theUrl", url);
    f.setArguments(extras);
    getActivity().getSuportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(f).commit();
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Wow cool! But if I want to display it in fragment WebFragment.class how do I change your code? FYI: the fragment is in the same activity with the WebView fragment :)

Comment: Make MyWebViewFragment extend WebViewFragment. Inside MyWebViewFragment's onCreate(...), get the extra: String url = getArguments().getString("theUrl"); Inside MyWebViewFragment's onResume(): getWebView().loadUrl(url);  Beware of NullPointerException when using url variable without checks.